# Ruby Heapsort: `sink': undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, algorithm, heapsort

I'm currently working on [Robert Sedgewicks Algorithm's](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/24pq/) book. I'm trying to implement Heap sort but I'm coming across an error

> 'sink': undefined method >' for nil:NilClass

This error happens because of the when the array is pass to the `sort` method it has 11 elements at 0 index. when it swaps index `n` (the number of elements in the array) with 1 is comparing `nil` with a string. Meaning `n` is 11 but there is no 11 index because the array index starts at 0.

Here is the Java implementation for the Heap sort method in the book:

```
 public static void sort(Comparable[] a)
  {
     int N = a.length;
     for (int k = N/2; k >= 1; k--)
        sink(a, k, N);
     while (N > 1)
     {
        exch(a, 1, N--);
        sink(a, 1, N);
     }
}
```

Now here is the implementation in Ruby:

```
  def sort(a)
    n = a.length
    k = n/2
    while k >= 1
      sink(a, k, n)
      k -= 1
    end
    
    while n > 1
      swap(a, 1, n)
      n -= 1
      sink(a, 1, n)
    end
    a
  end
```

Now, in the book the array disregards the position `a[0]` and starts at `a[1]` but I'm a bit unclear how that is being done in the `sort` method in the Java implementation. It is also a bit strange to me that the method would required to be pass an array starting at index `1`. So my understanding is that the `sort` method in the Java implementation will  set the array.

[image]

Notice in the example how the first element in the array starts at index 1 `a[1]`. Is this being done in the `sort` method? Meaning rearranging the array to start at index 1?

Is the Ruby implementation of `sort` in Ruby correct? Or is there an error?

Full implementation of Heap sort.

```
class Heap
  # Trickledown
  def sink(a, k, n)
    while 2 * k <= n
      j = 2 * k # child

      if !a[j + 1].nil? # check if there is a right child
        j += 1 if j > 1 && less(a, j, j + 1) # if left child less than right child
      end

      break if !less(a, k, j) # If parent greater than child break

      swap(a, k, j)
      k = j
    end
  end

  def sort(a)
    n = a.length
    k = n / 2

    while k >= 1
      sink(a, k, n)
      k -= 1
    end

    while n > 1
      swap(a, 1, n)
      n -= 1
      sink(a, 1, n)
    end
    a
  end

  def less(pq, i, j)
    pq[i - 1] < pq[j - 1]
  end

  def swap(a, i, j)
    temp = a[i - 1]
    a[i - 1] = a[j - 1]
    a[j - 1] = temp
  end
end

input = ["S", "O", "R", "T", "E", "X", "A", "M", "P", "L", "E"]

heap = Heap.new
p heap.sort(input)
```

When I edit the `less` and `swap` methods to address the off by one index in the array it those works correctly on some but not all the elements. If you check the last line is a TEST to run the script but it returns:

```
["A", "M", "E", "L", "E", "O", "P", "R", "S", "T", "X"]
```

But the correct answer is

```
 ["A", "E", "E", "L", "M", "O", "P", "R", "S", "T", "X"]
```

Comment: Error message points on `sink` method. Only line that could have `>` call on `nil` is `break if a[k] > a[j]`. I guess that after some `swap` call(s) initial array is damaged by `nil`s because a[a.size] is `nil` and your `n` can reach `s.size`

Comment: correct, that what I described in the post. But how is that being done in the Java implementation? Notice how array starts at index 1.

Comment: You are given the intermediate snapshots of the data. Trace your execution and verify your snapshots are identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error was coming from the following line:

```
if !a[j + 1].nil? # check if there is a right child
```

This line checks if a right node exist. The problem in the heap sort implementation is that we are decreasing `n` by one in each iteration.

```
 while n > 1
    swap(a, 1, n)
    n -= 1
    sink(a, 1, n)
 end
```

Thus we are not keeping track of the elements store in the array that are over index `n`. Although the array has values stored in the array we are treating only the `a[0]` to `a[n]` as a heap.
[image]

there for I shouldn't check to see if `a[j + 1]` is nil rather see if  `j + 1` is less than or equal to `n`.

```
  def sink(a, k, n)
    while 2 * k <= n
      j = 2 * k # child

      if j + 1 <= n # check if there is a right child
        j += 1 if j > 1 && less(a, j, j + 1) # if left child less than right child
      end

      break if !less(a, k, j) # If parent greater than child break
      swap(a, k, j)
      k = j
    end
  end
```